# How can i use AutoResetEventHandler to signal Main thread function to start threads again once the first set of worker threads are done processing

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Requirement :-** At any given point of time only 4 threads should be calling four different functions. As soon as these threads complete, next available thread should call the same functions.

**Current code :-** This seems to be the worst possible way to achieve something like this. While(True) will cause unnecessary CPU spikes and i could see CPU rising to 70% when running the following code.

**Question :-** How can i use AutoResetEventHandler to signal Main thread  Process() function to start next 4 threads again once the first 4 worker threads are done processing without wasting CPU cycles. Please suggest

```
public class Demo
{
    object protect = new object();
    private int counter;
    public void Process()
    {
        int maxthread = 4;
        while (true)
        {
            if (counter <= maxthread)
            {
                counter++;
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomething));
                t.Start();
            }
        }
    }
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //simulate long running process
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (protect)
            {
                counter--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about why you want to do that? I ask because there may be better solutions already supported by the .Net framework.

Comment: I have been asked to analyse this code and provide better ways to accomplish this so that CPU spikes can be prevented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to achieve what you want in a simpler way. If you run the code below you'll notice that an entry is written after each thread terminates and only after all four threads terminate the `"Finished batch"` entry is written.

This sample uses the [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) to wait for the completion of all tasks. The code uses an infinite loop for illustration purposes only, you should calculate the `hasPendingWork` condition based on your requirements so that you only start a new batch of tasks if required.

For example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool hasPendingWork = true;
    do
    {
        var tasks = InitiateTasks();

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine("Finished batch...");
    } while (hasPendingWork);
}

private static Task[] InitiateTasks()
{
    var tasks = new Task[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
    {
        int wait = 1000*i;

        tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(wait);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished waiting: {0}", wait);
        });
    }

    return tasks;
}
```

One other thing, from the textual requirement section on your question I'm lead to believe that a batch of four new threads should only start after all previously four threads completed. However the code you posted is not compatible with that requirement, since it starts a new thread immediately after a previous thread terminate. You should clarify what exactly is your requirement.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to start a thread immediately after one of the four threads terminate you can still use TPL instead of starting new threads explicitly but you can limit the number of running threads to four by using a [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx). For example:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim TaskController = new SemaphoreSlim(4);

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var random = new Random(570);

    while (true)
    {
        // Blocks thread without wasting CPU
        // if the number of resources (4) is exhausted
        TaskController.Wait();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started");
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 3000));
            Console.WriteLine("Completed");
            // Releases a resource meaning TaskController.Wait will unblock
            TaskController.Release();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: have updated the requirement. provided Code is what exactly needs to be done.. Thanks for pointing it out.